# How can I submit XML data in request to WSDL server?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl

I want to submit XML data from web service client to WSDL server. This is the WSDL file : http://www.nemsis.org/v3/downloads/NEMSIS_V3_12_core.wsdl  and I am calling function "SubmitData" but it is giving errors :: stdClass Object ( [requestType] => SubmitData [requestHandle] => Server Fatal Error #11. There is no payload in the SOAP message. Please make sure the SOAP message is compiled properly. [statusCode] => -101 )

This is the code which I have written::

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/nemsis/data.xml');
    try{
        $sClient = new SoapClient('https://www.nemsis.org/NemsisV3Validator/NemsisWsService?wsdl');
        $parameters->username = "******";
        $parameters->password = "*********";
        $parameters->organization = "Organisation";
        $parameters->requestType = "SubmitData";
        $parameters->submitPayload = $xml;
        $parameters->requestDataSchema = "62";
        $parameters->schemaVersion = "3.2.6";
        $parameters->additionalInfo = "Hakuna matata";
        $response = $sClient->SubmitData($parameters);
        print_r($response);
    } 
    catch(SoapFault $e)
    {
        var_dump($e);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post your request and response. You can obtain them with Wireshark, for example.

Comment: The request code is the above one " $response = $sClient->SubmitData($parameters);" and response is :: stdClass Object ( [requestType] => SubmitData [requestHandle] => Server Fatal Error #11. There is no payload in the SOAP message. Please make sure the SOAP message is compiled properly. [statusCode] => -101 )

Comment: Yes, that's your code, but I would like to see the product of your code, i.e. SOAP request and SOAP response. Something is probably wrong with the body of SOAP request.